# World map particle effects javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am looking for an effect as below the link http://www.google.com/zeitgeist/2012/, If you look at the map the dots are having an pulse effect + its like pops and fades back.

http://www.google.com/zeitgeist/2012/

[image]
Can any one help me in finding this kind of effect please.

Comment: They are probably just on a `fadeToggle()` loop. There may be some analytics behind it, obviously, but that's how simple it is to achieve the animation style. have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Comment: if you look at the map carefully the dots are placed only at the area of locations. how to achieve that?

Comment: Google will have a database of all searches that happen, each search will have a "geotag" pointing to a location on the earth using LAT/LONG. They will be using this data to show points on the map, the size of the dot will relate to the amount of searches etc.

Comment: If you're interested in this kind of Visual Analysis, I'd suggest looking into D3: http://d3js.org/

Comment: If you examine the code of the page, you can see that Three.js is used. This map is drawn on a canvas, I guess there's already pretty complex stuff behind this.

Comment: @JeremyThille ur rite.. i have seen that they are using three.js :) yes its loading through canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one div with the map and then another div with the spots overlaying the first one, both of the same size and absolutly positioned one on top of the other. Then with css animation, you can animate the opacity of the second one, generating the fliquering effect.

Comment: Since all the dots don't blink at the same time, you can even stack 3 or 4 layers and make them fade in/out at different moments.